# AWS Lambda layer files location

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have node.js lambda app and I created a layer for qrcode and added my layer to my lambda function.

now when I goto my lambda and layers, I see my layer with the following details: myqrcodelayer

and when I reference it in my function, i get below error:

```
 "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
 "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'qrcode'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n-   /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
"trace": [
"Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'qrcode'",
```

I call my qrcode in lambda like below:

```
const QRCode = require('/opt/myQRCodeLayer/qrcode');
```

Comment: maybe just `const QRCode = require('qrcode');`

Comment: I did that also not working, do you know where the layers are stored so I can get the path correctly and know what is going on

Comment: did you uploaded the node_modules folder to lambda ?

Comment: yes I uploaded node_modules